# What is the best way to send an object as a query parameter of a browser url in javascript

Tags: javascript, url, query-string

I am working on a project in javascript where the user can add multiple filters, drill down through hierarchy etc to search through data. Once a user drills down, adds filters and gets some results, I want the user to be able to share these results as a url to someone else. Now, the search query is going to be a complicated object and I want to send that query as part of browser url. I know there are multiple ways of doing it. But what is the best way?

The following is an example query

```
{
    "category": 1,
    "categoryDetails": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "category 321"
    },
    "start": "2020-03-20",
    "end": "2020-05-05",
    "filters": [{
        "key": "viewby",
        "value": "something",
        "label": "something else"
    }, {
        "key": "color",
        "value": "0",
        "label": "black"
    }, {
        "key": "color",
        "value": "1",
        "label": "blue"
    }, {
        "key": "color",
        "value": "2",
        "label": "white"        
    }, {
        "key": "tags",
        "value": "cl",
        "label": "clean"
    }, {
        "key": "tags",
        "value": "wi",
        "label": "winter"
    }]
}
```

I know I can stringify the json object and send it

```
url = `/search?query="{\"category\":1,\"categoryDetails\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"category 321\"},\"start\":\"2020-03-20\",\"end\":\"2020-05-05\",\"filters\":[{\"key\":\"viewby\",\"value\":\"something\",\"label\":\"something else\"},{\"key\":\"color\",\"value\":\"0\",\"label\":\"black\"},{\"key\":\"color\",\"value\":\"1\",\"label\":\"blue\"},{\"key\":\"color\",\"value\":\"2\",\"label\":\"white\"},{\"key\":\"tags\",\"value\":\"cl\",\"label\":\"clean\"},{\"key\":\"tags\",\"value\":\"wi\",\"label\":\"winter\"}]}"{\"key\":\"tags\",\"value\":\"winter\",\"label\":\"winter\"}]}"
```

Or convert it into a base64 string

```
url = `search?query=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
```

Is there a better of doing this? What are some best practices followed while doing this?

Comment: A standard query parameter is like `?category=category%20321&start=2020-03-20& ...`, i.e. key-value pairs, both percent encoded.

Comment: @Teemu I changed the example data. The object can be quite complicated. Is it really the best way to send it as it is.

Comment: Put it in a FormData object and post a form? This is more or less opinion based, there's so many ways to do this. Creating a function which formats the query correctly is not hard to code, you'd need to percent encode everything anyway.

Answer (score 0):

anything, but better to avoid slashes with usage of `encodeURI` function.

```
const params = {
    "category": 1,
    "categoryDetails": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "category 321"
    },
    "start": "2020-03-20",
    "end": "2020-05-05",
    "filters": [{
        "key": "viewby",
        "value": "something",
        "label": "something else"
    }, {
        "key": "color",
        "value": "0",
        "label": "black"
    }, {
        "key": "color",
        "value": "1",
        "label": "blue"
    }, {
        "key": "color",
        "value": "2",
        "label": "white"        
    }, {
        "key": "tags",
        "value": "cl",
        "label": "clean"
    }, {
        "key": "tags",
        "value": "wi",
        "label": "winter"
    }]
};

const url = `/search?query=${encodeURI(JSON.stringify(params))}`;
```

```
/search?query=%7B%22category%22:1,%22categoryDetails%22:%7B%22id%22:1,%22name%22:%22category%20321%22%7D,%22start%22:%222020-03-20%22,%22end%22:%222020-05-05%22,%22filters%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22viewby%22,%22value%22:%22something%22,%22label%22:%22something%20else%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22color%22,%22value%22:%220%22,%22label%22:%22black%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22color%22,%22value%22:%221%22,%22label%22:%22blue%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22color%22,%22value%22:%222%22,%22label%22:%22white%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22tags%22,%22value%22:%22cl%22,%22label%22:%22clean%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22tags%22,%22value%22:%22wi%22,%22label%22:%22winter%22%7D%5D%7D
```

there's no difference between json or base64, just usability for you, both of them are encoded data.